# How to create excel dashboard with given data?

Tags: excel, pivot-table

A job interview recently gave me a screening assessment that I was unable to do correctly because of my inexperience with excel. What is the best way to have completed this assignment?

[excel assessment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S11gu.png)

The assignment is to create a user friendly dashboard for the week of 5/25 – 5/29 that reflects the progress towards goal for participation of each meal service.  This dashboard will be shared with each campus’ administration staff as well as cafeteria managers and will be referenced during strategy meetings to improve participation % across the district.

Use the data provided in the Dashboard Assessment file provided to you to build the dashboard.

Note: You can choose any format you would like to present the deliverable.  Make any necessary assumptions, just note them.

Our school has a departmental goal for each campus to meet 85% breakfast,80% lunch & 10% supper participation.

Comment: Is there a “correct” answer?

Comment: My first step would be to get the numbers for that week for each item shown, then consider averages or percentages to (assumed) targets or goals or even change compared to previous weeks. Issues are how do weeks compare? Seasonality? Local events? Once you start to understand the story then you can create a layout ie dashboard.

Comment: @SolarMike no there is no correct answer they just want to see what I can make out of it.

Comment: So you don’t even have to assume a goal, perhaps comparing the last week to the current week.

Comment: @SolarMike forgot to mention that the departmental goal for each campus to meet 85% breakfast,80% lunch & 10% supper participation.

Comment: Yes, read that which explains my previous comment.